# Facebook permission request, endless redirect loop

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have this code:

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => 'xxxxxxx',
'secret' => 'yyyyyyy',
'baseUrl' => 'http://xxx.yyy.zz/',
'appBaseUrl' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxx/',
'fileUpload' => 'true',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$params = array(
  scope => 'publish_stream,user_photos',
  redirect_uri => 'http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxx?sk=app_123456789'
    );

if ($user){
    ....
}

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

if ($user){
// nothing
}else{
  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">top.location.href = \"".$loginUrl."\";</script>";
}
```

My problem is, that it gets into an endless loop... reloads the page over and over. 
Can someone help me to fix this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the main logic was not int the index.php. After i put everything back into that, the redirection stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your `redirect_uri`. Try to define the real path to your url (www.yourdomain.com/app/index.php) instead, since Facebook will send a POST (including a code) to that url and won't pass it with the app data or signed request to your iFrame application.

Comment: but if i change it to the APP's hosting URL, it will leave the Facebook page, where it's embed (iFrame)

Comment: then either try to replace `top.location.href` with `document.location.href`, or set your redirect_uri to a single script page on your server (with the fb sdk initialized, e.g. http://yourdomain.com/fb_auth.php) and redirect to your tab url. the user should be authenticated then.

Comment: no change :( tried it. redirect_uri is a .php (facebook array included) with a JS reddirection, but it still gets into reload loop :( i don't get it what could be the problem....